# How to keep track of how much memory is leaked?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm working on a homework assignment that requires me to write a program that leaks memory, keep track of how much memory it is leaking until it crashes.

My general thoughts for the program would be to continuously reassign a malloc pointer.

Here's my code so far:

```
char *oldMemory = malloc(125000); //1MB of memory.
char *newMemory = malloc(125000);
oldMemory = newMemory;
```

- Is there are way to put this in a loop and repeatedly orphan a
  certain amount of memory until the program can no longer allocate any memory and     crashes?
- How can I keep track of how much memory was leaked before the program crashed?

Thanks for your time and expertise!

Comment: `malloc(125000)` will give you 125,000 bytes, or about 122KB. Nowhere near 1MB.

Comment: You're right. I typed it into [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) to convert that value to bytes, and I must have used megabits instead.

Comment: Just for fun: `while (new int);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Count the size of the leaked allocations.

Don't forget to print the size leaked on each iteration - so you see the result even if the program crashes.  The program should not crash if you test for failed allocations before accessing it.

Hence:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { ALLOCSIZE = 125000 };

int main(void)
{
    long long size = 0;
    char *space = malloc(ALLOCSIZE);
    while (space != 0)
    {
        size += ALLOCSIZE;
        printf("OK %lld\n", size);
        memset(space, '\0', ALLOCSIZE);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The Linux OOM might confuse things; it allows over-commitment of memory.  You'd have to access the allocated memory before leaking it - hence the `memset()` (or you could use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`).

Comment: I tried this code with allocsize as a long long = 12500000000000000, and the amount of memory usage peaks at 192,248KB. I'm running this on  Windows 7 at the moment, if that helps.

Comment: Instead of using `malloc`/`free` directly, you could write your own function that add/subtract an "outstanding bytes" variable. It would make sense to keep this variable static inside the file you define these functions in. This way, if the value is ever nonzero, you know you've allocated something without freeing it.

Answer (score 0):

when you allocate some block of memory in C you should be responsible to free it using
`free()` function.
if you want to make sure that your program won't crash due to some memory leaks.
you can use `assert()` function when asking for more memory or using the allocated memory.
and you should check on the returned pointer returned from malloc , if it's NULL so the allocation failed. >> Be careful in linux kernels `malloc()` won't return NULL ever,due  to "memory overcommit"

Comment: He's attempting to leak memory and needs to track the memory leaked.